# WSO2 ESB axis2ns248:INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am followed steps from http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2015/03/tutorial-calling-stored-procedures-with-in-and-out-parameters-using-wso2-data-services-server-1/ and tried this tutorial many times still error appear in response  INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR

**Source Code of service**

```
<data name="MySQLSPSample" serviceNamespace="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" transports="http https local">
   <config enableOData="false" id="SampleDataSourceMySQL">
      <property name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/esb_sample</property>
      <property name="username">root</property>
   </config>
   <query id="getEmployeeDetailsQuery" useConfig="SampleDataSourceMySQL">
      <sql>CALL GetEmployeeByID(?)</sql>
      <result element="Employees" rowName="Employee">
         <element column="FirstName" name="FirstNameValue" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="LastName" name="LastNameValue" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="Team" name="TeamName" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param name="EmpID" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
   </query>
   <operation name="getEmployeebyID">
      <call-query href="getEmployeeDetailsQuery">
         <with-param name="EmpID" query-param="EmpID"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

http://192.168.5.246:9763/services/MySQLSPSample?tryit

**Request>>**

```
<body>
   <p:getEmployeebyID xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:EmpID xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">101</xs:EmpID>
   </p:getEmployeebyID>
</body>
```

**Reseponse>>**

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:axis2ns248="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
   <soapenv:Code>
      <soapenv:Value>axis2ns248:INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR</soapenv:Value>
   </soapenv:Code>
   <soapenv:Reason>
      <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR Nested Exception:- javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:EmpID DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR Source Data Service:- Name: MySQLSPSample Location: \MySQLSPSample.dbs Description: N/A Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice Current Request Name: getEmployeebyID Current Params: {}  </soapenv:Text>
   </soapenv:Reason>
   <soapenv:Detail>
      <axis2ns247:DataServiceFault xmlns:axis2ns247="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
         <axis2ns247:current_params>{}</axis2ns247:current_params>
         <axis2ns247:source_data_service>
            <axis2ns247:data_service_name>MySQLSPSample</axis2ns247:data_service_name>
            <axis2ns247:description>N/A</axis2ns247:description>
            <axis2ns247:location>\MySQLSPSample.dbs</axis2ns247:location>
            <axis2ns247:default_namespace>http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice</axis2ns247:default_namespace>
         </axis2ns247:source_data_service>
         <axis2ns247:ds_code>INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR</axis2ns247:ds_code>
         <axis2ns247:current_request_name>getEmployeebyID</axis2ns247:current_request_name>
      </axis2ns247:DataServiceFault>
   </soapenv:Detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

**Note:**  this will works fine when I add default value 101 in service configuration

Comment: I have had issues when there was a namespace defined in the same tag as the parameter - i.e. try sending it without the namespace.

Comment: removed serviceNamespace="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" but still same error.

Comment: I meant in the request itself i.e. instead of having: `<xs:EmpID xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">101</xs:EmpID>`, you should have `<EmpID>101</EmpID>`

Comment: yea used <EmpID>101</EmpID> and remove <xs: TO </ex:EmpID> whole tag but still same error :)

Comment: This happens when you use the "Try It" functionality, right? Have you tried loading the wsdl in a tool like SoapUI and sending a request through it?

Comment: I put your dss service in my DSS 3.5.1, create the DB using the steps in the tutorial and try with the tryit and it work well.